# How to ignore HLint's arrow hints?

Tags: haskell, lint

I use [HLint](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hlint/) on my Haskell code, but not all the warnings/errors are very useful. In particular, the arrow hints because I never use arrows.

How do I get HLint to ignore all the arrow hints?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint#customizing-the-hints) indicates that you can do so with an annotation at the top of your source, or in a hint file that you can pass with the `--hint` flag.

Comment: @bheklilr Yes I read that, but it doesn't indicate how I can specify which hints I want to ignore. I'd specifically like to ignore all the arrow related hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example, if you had the code:

```
map (\a -> (head a, length a)) someList
```

HLint would print out:

```
Warning: Use &&&
Found:
    \a -> (head a, length a)
Why not:
    head Control.Arrow.&&& length
```

Then you could ignore this by adding:

```
{-# ANN module "HLint: ignore Use &&&" #-}
```

At the top of your file.  Alternative, you could create a file `ana.hlint` containing:

```
ignore "Use &&&"
```

Then use `hlint` as:

```
> hlint --hint=ana.hlint source_code.hs
```

Comment: Thanks. This is  what I was looking for. But how do you know to use the string "Use &&&" ? I don't see that string in [Default.hs](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint/blob/master/data/Default.hs) anywhere.

Comment: @Ana: That confused me too. I think it's just based on the error message which is produced based on the righthand side of the hint's definition.

Comment: I'm not sure where it's defined, but I figured it out because it says "Warning: Use &&&".